# How do shoot apical meristems know which leaf arragement to set out based on DNA?

Tags: plant-anatomy

Shoot apical meristems are responsible for leaf and stem growth.
However when developing, how does the meristem develop the arrangement of the leaves? Like, alternate, opposite, whorled or basal.

Ive tried to search for any answers but to no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, leaf growth inhibits the growth of newer leaves.

Aspects related to this inhibition (distance from the old leaf, inhibition over time, architecture of the growing shoot, etc.) influence where on the stem the next leaf will appear. By varying the details of these parameters, one can model leaf arrangements that match most of the common leaf arrangements found in nature. Presumably there are genes that control aspects of these parameters.

https://phys.org/news/2019-06-unusual-japanese-recalculation-equation-leaf.html

https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1007044